# Inserting data, Update if "ID" exists already

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using table adapters to insert data into my database:

```
JUTDMSTableAdapters.textBooksTableAdapter bookTableAdapter;
bookTableAdapter = new JUTDMSTableAdapters.textBooksTableAdapter();
JUTDMSTableAdapters.CourseTableAdapter courseTableAdapter;
courseTableAdapter = new JUTDMSTableAdapters.CourseTableAdapter();
courseTableAdapter.Insert( CourseID: txtCourseID.Text, CourseTitle: txtCourseTitle.Text);
bookTableAdapter.Insert( thirteenISBN: txt13ISBN.Text, CourseID: txtCourseID.Text, BookTitle: txtBookTitle.Text, Ancillary: txtAncillary.Text,
BookActive: txtBookActive.Text, ActiveDate: txtActiveDate.Text, InactiveDate: txtInactiveDate.Text, Author: txtAuthor.Text,
            Imprint: txtImprint.Text, Publisher: txtPublisher.Text, EditionAndDate: txtEditionDate.Text,
VendorISBN: vendISBN, tenISBN: txt10ISBN.Text, ebookAvailable: txtEBookAvailable.Text, eISBN: txtEISBN.Text, Notes: txtNotes.Text);
```

When I insert a new text book I enter in the "CourseID" and it adds the record to the parent table "Course" My problem is that every time I add a new text book, if the courseID already exists it still adds a new record to the parent "Course" table. I need to UPDATE the current database if the CourseID exists and ADD if it doesnt, but I havent seen anything like this regarding table adapters.

Comment: you need to show your sql in regards to the `If Exist` also why don't you add the Sql to a stored procedure vs relying on the sql that's attached to the TableAdapters. you need to show all relevant code..

Comment: what I was wondering is if there is a way to put this insert in an if statement and check for the courseID. I havent a clue. Never used c# before and this is my first ever application

Comment: have you ever purchased a new or used car..? if yes ; then do you have to learn how to `Learn how to Drive again..?`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the course is already exist by separated query and then insert or update the course.